Have URL or IP addresses connected via WiFi or cable
My Ubuntu 20.04.6 system connects to the remote internet via WiFi and via a cable.
I want to visit some web sites via WiFi and others via cable.
Can I configure somewhere that some URLs or IP addresses connect to the external internet via WiFi and others via cable?

Never heard of such a thing. What research have you done?

Yes, it is solvable under certain assumptions. You can use routing table settings and static paths, but a number of circumstances affect whether it will work correctly. Among other things, it depends on whether or not both of your interfaces are on the same IP network, in the same broadcast domain. The setup requires you to be familiar with network routing issues and be able to verify which of the two interfaces the packets of a particular connection go and come to for your chosen destination address, such as a remote web server.
The result of your efforts may result in, among other things, so-called asymmetric routing, which is considered an undesirable phenomenon in a network.
I will assume that each of your two interfaces on your Ubuntu PC has a different IP address. By configuring this, you can determine which gateway out of the Ubuntu PC packets will go to which destination address or network. This will affect the path out. But the return of packets from the remote destination to the PC is determined by routing in the reverse direction, typically determined by your home router. It may be that packets go out one interface and replies come back on another. This is the case of asymmetric routing.
Theoretically, you can also affect the routing on your router by adding static paths. But normal IP routing is based on destination addresses, not source addresses. And when returning packets, you would need to account for routing by the source address of the remote server. Source routing is not usually enabled on network elements and is not recommended for security reasons.
Besides, when using static routing, in addition to routing, you need to set address assignment to your Ubuntu. You would either have to work with manually setting the computer's IP addresses or use static reservations on the DHCP server.
You can set up advanced routing on Ubuntu using iproute2, preparing multiple sets of routing tables instead of the usual one set. But overall the setup is so complex that I don't recommend going into something like this without a deeper understanding. You'll spend too much time tweaking the settings and looking for causes of malfunctioning, and eventually it will stop working after a while anyway, e.g. because your target web server uses a different one of several possible IP addresses (changed DNS record or multiple DNS record) and you'll have to modify the settings.
